# What can I do with leftover commendations?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So I made it to Dromond Kass, and I took with me a handful of unused Planetary Commendations from Korriban.

Is there any use for these (now outdated) commendations, or will I be lugging them around in my currency window for the rest of the game?

Comment: Even if you spend them all, there will be a "Korriban Commendation      0" line in that window.

Comment: All planetary commendations are now just plain Planetary Commendations, so for example you can use ones from Korriban 30+ levels later on Corellia without issue.  I think that may make this Too Localized now.

Comment: @MatthewRead I think an edit to Powerlord's answer might suffice in this instance, since planetary commendations still exist (they're just not planet specific anymore)

Comment: Fair enough, I've made the edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Patch 2.0, planetary commendations all got combined into a single type.  Any commendations you don't immediately spend at the Korriban vendor can be saved and spent at the Dromund Kaas vendor after a couple more levels, and so on, all the way up to Makeb.

The commendations vendors are located on the appropriate planet or on the Fleet (in the area of the map marked "Supplies").

Once you've finished levelling, the best idea is to buy the best lockbox you can afford (e.g., the purple one from the Makeb vendor) with the commendations you have left.

Comment: An epic lockbox usually sells for 24 commendations, and the item inside is BoE so can be auctioned. It could be worth it to redo a heroic-4 quest or flashpoint (they can be soloed when you seriously outlevel them), or help some lower level guildies doing so.

Comment: The epic lockbox, when not opened, also has a high vendor price (I recall about 2300 credits). This might be a bug, of course, but instead of opening, consider vendoring it unopened.